# Set Style for Cells in .docx with Open XML SDK

Tags: c#, wpf, openxml-sdk

I created a Table in my .docx File and changed the Alignment, Font etc.
Now I generate new rows via C#, but they don't have the same Alignment, Font etc. like the cells above.

How can I set up something like a .css file for the rows?
Following shows how my Code adds a row into the table:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow();

TableCell positionCell = new TableCell();
positionCell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(i.ToString()))));

TableCell bezeichnungCell = new TableCell();
descCell.Append(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text("Description"))));

tr.Append(positionCell);
tr.Append(descCell);
t.Append(tr);
```

Also I can't use something like `positionCell.Alignment = Alignment.Center` like xaml.